# Wait for ServiceWorker to complete registering before subscribing

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, push-notification, service-worker

I am using a ServiceWorker to implement user notifications. When the user first visits the site and approves the notification, the ServiceWorker is registered and subscribed to:

```
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
 console.log('Service Worker is supported');
 navigator.serviceWorker.register('/js/sw.js').then(function(reg) {
   if(/chrom(e|ium)/.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase())){
       reg.pushManager.subscribe({
           userVisibleOnly: true
       }).then(function(sub) {
           console.log('endpoint:', sub.endpoint);
           endpoint = sub.endpoint;
           fetch(MY_API+encodeURIComponent(endpoint), {
                    credentials: 'include'
                 })
       });
   }
 }).catch(function(err) {
   console.log(':^(', err);
 });
}
```

On the very first visit, this failes with:

```
Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Subscription failed - no active Service Worker
```

From the second visit on, everything is OK because the ServiceWorker is already active at that time. Looks like this is a timing issue. How can I be sure the ServiceWorker has been registered successfully and is active before I try to subscribe to it?

I tried using `navigator.serviceWorker.ready` as suggested below:

```
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
 console.log('Service Worker is supported');
 navigator.serviceWorker.register('/js/sw.js').then(function(sreg) {
   console.log(':^)', sreg);
   navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(function(reg) {
       if(/chrom(e|ium)/.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase())){
           reg.pushManager.subscribe({
               userVisibleOnly: true
           }).then(function(sub) {
               console.log('endpoint:', sub.endpoint);
               endpoint = sub.endpoint;
               fetch("https://www.wettfreun.de/?page=fetch&s=1&endpoint="+encodeURIComponent(endpoint), {credentials: 'include'})
           });
       }
   });
 }).catch(function(err) {
   console.log(':^(', err);
 });
}
```

Now the part inside `navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then()` is never called.

Comment: Why are you using the Push API only on Chrome/Chromium?

Comment: Because my backend currently only supports GCM

Comment: Without payloads, the Web Push standard is really simple to implement (basically a POST request to the endpoint URL).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use [ServiceWorkerContainer.ready](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorkerContainer/ready).

Example from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/):

```
function subscribe() {
  var subscribeButton = document.querySelector('.js-subscribe-button');
  subscribeButton.disabled = false;

  navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(function(serviceWorkerRegistration) {
    serviceWorkerRegistration.pushManager.subscribe()
      .then(function(subscription) {
        // The subscription was successful
        subscribeButton.disabled = true;
        return sendSubscriptionToServer(subscription);
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        if (Notification.permission === 'denied') {
          console.log('Permission for Notifications was denied');
          subscribeButton.disabled = true;
        } else {
          console.log('Unable to subscribe to push.', error);
          subscribeButton.disabled = false;
        }
      });
  });
}
```

Comment: Could you show an example? There's no registration in the doc you provided. Where should the ready() call be made?

Comment: I've added an example from MDN.

Comment: Ah, maybe you also want to know how to make the service worker active the first time you load the page?
Look at https://serviceworke.rs/immediate-claim.html.

Comment: Thanks Marco, I already have the skipWaiting() call in my install listener in the service worker. As I said, the example from MDN doesn't include the service worker registration (only the subscription process, the service worker is already registered earlier). Maybe this is by design and we simply should not start the subscription process on page load but rather do that on user interaction.

Comment: Do you also have the call to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clients/claim?
It's not by design, I'm subscribing on load and after waiting for ready in one of my projects and it works.

Comment: Figured it out, you're right, it works using serviceWorker.ready. But the ready promise is only fired, when the service worker js-file is located in the root directory of the website, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29874068/navigator-serviceworker-is-never-ready for details.

Comment: Note that `.ready` resolves when *any* service worker controls the page (it could be yesterday's service worker). If the code you want to run has a dependency on a *particular* service worker, then you'll need to do [something like this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35705984/11543).